# shortauthor and shorttitle displayed as (cit. shortauthor, shorttitle) enclosed in bibliography using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

been trying too long now on this: I would like to enclose e.g. the following text:

> (cit. Doe, Commercial Laws) *[name in smallcaps]*

in the end of each of my entries in the bibliography before the period, e.g.:

> Doe John, Commercial Laws of Canada, Toronto 1999 (cit. Doe,
>   Commercial Law). *[name in smallcaps]*

Using biblatex and biber, I found the following and put in in the preamble of my *.tex file:

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{
   \printtext[parens]{
   \unspace{cit. }\printnames{shortauthor}\addcomma\addspace\printfield{shorttitle}\unspace
   \printnames{shorttitle}}
}
```

This generates (position in the beginning instead of the end!):

> (cit. Doe, Commercial Laws) Doe John, Commercial Laws of Canada, Toronto 1999.

Does anyone have a solution to my problem? Also, is it possible to generate shortauthor and shorttitle with biblatex without defining these labels in the *.bib file?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to put the text at the end of the entry you have to use the `finentry` biblatex macro, not the `begentry` one, thus, you can replace `begentry` with `finentery` in your code, and add `\finentry` at the end to print the final period.

```
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{
   \printtext[parens]{
   \unspace{cit. }\printnames{shortauthor}\addcomma\addspace\printfield{shorttitle}\unspace
   \printnames{shorttitle}}%
   \finentry
}
```

Notice that the `\unspace` are not necesasry and they can be elimated.

The field `shortauthor` and `shorttitle` should be given in the `bib` file (it is possible to use some of the `map` features of `biber` to extract them from `author` and `title`). However, it seems to me that what you want can be achieved using the `labelname` and `labeltitle` fields (for `labeltitle` should use `shorttitle` if present in the `bib`).

```
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
  \printtext{cit.}\addspace
  \textsc{\printnames{labelname}}\addcomma\addspace
  \printfield{labeltitle}}
  \finentry
  }
```

Comment: All that `\unspace` business should be avoided with `%`.

Comment: Great, thanks to both of you (didn't know %)!

Comment: @Audrey Indeed. I copied the old code. I have updated the answer.